# Issue regarding accessing URLs with escaped characters in C#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have an issue with URLs being transformed automatically as they are being processed.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(this.url);

     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
     request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
     request.Method = "GET";
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Apologies for the long urls
In this case: this.url is correct

```
(https://zencoder-live.s3.amazonaws.com:443/ec03a97b1f726d8ee65774313a100db5%2Fa54779efdf5d1f64ac82954c870beb12.mp4?Signature=nrc0U65Pe3PiORokhAscndLdP68%3D&Expires=1284625412&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIIEXNN2J4YDTRUVQ)
```

Whereas the url inside the Uri object is not

```
({https://zencoder-live.s3.amazonaws.com/ec03a97b1f726d8ee65774313a100db5/a54779efdf5d1f64ac82954c870beb12.mp4?Signature=nrc0U65Pe3PiORokhAscndLdP68=&Expires=1284625412&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIIEXNN2J4YDTRUVQ}
```

Note the differences of "%2F" --> "/". 
The same happens if I feed this.url straight into WebRequest and I get a 403 error from the S3 server because the signatures no longer match.

Is there a way to prevent such transformations from occuring?

EDIT: 
As this is a desktop application (sorry for not mentioning earlier) HTTPUtilities is not available but the URI class has a similar function so I tried that

this.url = Uri.EscapeUriString(this.url);
and this.url gets set to:

```
https://zencoder-live.s3.amazonaws.com:443/e09517d7841a9047f9ff7a2f015d2596%252F1e8e7e8e1a85665bc7e9b146ce444a88.mp4?Signature=6bs5vfOBUDeHeX2HdmrvVGDnDjE%253D&Expires=1284627002&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIIEXNN2J4YDTRUVQ
```

and then from within the HttpWebRequest Object:

```
https://zencoder-live.s3.amazonaws.com/e09517d7841a9047f9ff7a2f015d2596%252F1e8e7e8e1a85665bc7e9b146ce444a88.mp4?Signature=6bs5vfOBUDeHeX2HdmrvVGDnDjE%253D&Expires=1284627002&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIIEXNN2J4YDTRUVQ
```

The HttpWebRequest object has not transformed it at all so the URI is still incorrect. %2F gets converted to %252F and does not get converted back to %2F on creation of the Uri Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e55w41w(v=VS.71).aspx) class, which offers UrlDecode / UrlEncode methods.

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Please see edit in to the original question

Comment: I tried importing HttpUtility class but it just converts the entire string which the Uri/ HttpWebRequest reject:  "https%3a%2f%2fzencoder-live.s3.amazonaws.com%3a443%2f2e33f7d90e54b1e8816eb1d7d80e6b08%252Fe80da01b484e4c4167f944e1952a0577.mp4%3fSignature%3d08VGDqDybKH8QN5lDKHzn46Fy2M%253D%26Expires%3d1284688887%26AWSAccessKeyId%3dAKIAIIEXNN2J4YDTRUVQ"

Answer (score 1):

`%2F` in the first URL is being correctly transformed to `/`.
In order to stop this you must first [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) to ensure the `%` is encoded.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.url));
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as I am creating a console application HttpUtility is not available. See edit. I did try Uri.EscapeUriString but that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: I've tried your code, changing the user agent and using many different encoded versions of the URL and it's still doing the same `403 Forbidden` error for me too. The only suggestion I have is that the secure port connection isn't behaving.

Comment: Thanks for trying out the links! In what what could it not be behaving (I'm fairly new to C# but experienced in PHP)